# jsdom does not fetch scripts on local file system

Tags: jsdom

This is how i construct it:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

var htmlSource = fs.readFileSync("./test.html", "utf8");
var doc = jsdom.jsdom(htmlSource,  {
    features: {
    FetchExternalResources   : ['script'],
    ProcessExternalResources : ['script'],
    MutationEvents           : '2.0'
},
    parsingMode: "auto",
    created: function (error, window) {
        console.log(window.b); // always undefined
    }
});

jsdom.jQueryify(doc.defaultView, 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js', function() {

    console.log( doc.defaultView.b ); // undefined with local jquery in html
});
```

the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script src="./js/lib/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript">

var a = $("body"); // script crashes here
var b = "b";

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As soon as i replace the jquery path in the html with a http source it works. The local path is perfectly relative to the working dir of the shell / actual node script. To be honest i don't even know why i need jQueryify, but without it the window never has jQuery and even with it, it still needs the http source inside the html document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not telling jsdom where the base of your website lies. It has no idea how to resolve the (relative) path you give it (and tries to resolve from the default `about:blank`, which just doesn't work). This also the reason why it works with an absolute (http) URL, it doesn't need to know where to resolve from since it's absolute.

You'll need to provide the `url` option in your initialization to give it the base url (which should look like `file:///path/to/your/file`).

jQuerify just inserts a script tag with the path you give it - when you get the reference in the html working, you don't need it.

Comment: thank you but unfortunately i tested and that's not it. I can't get jquery working without jQueryify at all, even if i use an absolute http path. I also realized the created callback is the wrong point, i have to use doc.defaultView.b after the jsdom call.
But the script always seems to crash. Even if i don't call $, without jQueryify any external script (!) makes b undefined (no error via virtualConsole).

Comment: In fact, if you provide the full path of your juqery package, the program will work. I think it's issue in the path finder.

Answer (score 0):

I found out. I'll mark Sebmasters answer as accepted because it solved one of two problems. The other cause was that I didn't properly wait for the load event, thus the code beyond the external scripts wasn't parsed yet.

What i needed to do was after the jsdom() call add a load listener to doc.defaultView.

The reason it worked when using jQuerify was simply because it created enough of a timeout for the embedded script to load.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that: you should use the done option instead of created if you use it like that. done will catch more errors from later life cycles and will be executed after onload.

Comment: @Sebmaster: Oh and it's right there, in the documentation. Shame on me and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when full relative path of the jquery library to the `jQueryify` function. and I solved this problem by providing the full path instead.

```
const jsdom = require('node-jsdom')
const jqueryPath = __dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js'

window = jsdom.jsdom().parentWindow

jsdom.jQueryify(window, jqueryPath, function() {
    window.$('body').append('<div class="testing">Hello World, It works')
    console.log(window.$('.testing').text())
})
```